# Chrome's webkitSpeechRecognition ends randomly

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, speech-recognition

I'm using the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) to capture voice commands on my webpage, but the recognizer ends (it stops listening and fires the onend event) after a certain period of time.

Why does this happen? Can I prevent it?

Here is all the code needed to have a voice recognizing page (40 Lines) and reproduce the error. It will alert "end" when the recognizer stops listening.

```
<h1>Voice Recognizer</h1>

<script>

if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
    alert('Your browser does not support speech recognition.');
} else {
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;

    recognition.onstart = function() {
        console.log('started');
    }

    recognition.onresult = function() { 
        interim_transcript = '';

        for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            } else {
                interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
        }

        console.log('interim result:', interim_transcript);
        console.log('final reuslt:', final_transcript);
    }

    recognition.onerror = function() { alert('error'); }

    recognition.onend = function() { alert('end'); }

    function startListening(e){
        final_transcript = '';
        recognition.start();
    }

    startListening();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google tries to limit the amount of processed data because it loads their servers. Restart speech recognition once it is over or use some offline processing like [Pocketsphinx.JS](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js)

Answer (score 0):

First of all google has given 60 seconds of recording time as of now, and it is very efficient in listening, so i would suggest that you increase your speaking speed. If your speech takes more than 60 secs, then webkit will trigger the onspeechend() function that leads to stopping of your code. either way if you can write your own trigger for onspeechend() and again call your function from within, then it should work for you as it would start a new instance and would continue with your text, unless you clear it.